Find maximum value of $f(x,y)$ where $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b}$
Given that $x\geq 0,y\geq 0,x+y=10$ and $a+b=132$.
Let $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b} \tag{1}$$
If minimum value of $f(x,y)$ is $20$
then find the maximum value of $f(x,y)$.
My Attempt
$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+a-1}+\sqrt{(y+1)^2+b-1}\leq \sqrt{2\left((x+1)^2+a-1+(y+1)^2+b-1\right)}=\sqrt{2\left(x^2+y^2+2x+2y+1+a+b-1\right)}=\sqrt{2\left((x+y+1)^2+a+b-1\right)}=\sqrt{2\left(11^2+132-1\right)}=6\sqrt{14}$
$f(x,y) \leq 6\sqrt{14} \tag{2}$
Is my solution correct ? I have not used the information that minimum value of $f(x,y)$ equals $20$. Moreover equality will occur if $$x^2+2x+a=y^2+2y+b \tag{3}$$ which happens when $x=y$ and $a=b$ which does not seem to be happening here.

I removed the tags AM-GM & Cauchy-Schwarz , because those are not Question-related , might (or might not) be Solution-related. In Case you disagree , you could add that back.

You have made a mistake. Correction: $(x+y+1)^2=x^2+y^2+1+2(xy+x+y)$

You can think about the problem geometrically. Let $u=x+1$, $v=y+1$, $p^2=a-1$ and $q^2=b-1$. Then imagine a route from $(0,0)$ to $(p+q,12)$ in two straight lines: from $(0,0)$ to $(p,u)$ and then from $(p,u)$ to $(p+q,12)$. The length of this route is $\sqrt{p^2+u^2}+\sqrt{q^2+v^2}$, which is the expression in the problem. Its minimum is clearly when the point $(p,u)$ lies on the line from $(0,0)$ to $(p+q,12)$, so the ratios $p:q$ and $u:v$ are equal. Then, knowing that the minimum distance is $20$ gives $20^2=(p+q)^2+12^2$, but $p^2+q^2=130$, so $p, q = 7, 9$.
We need $u,v>1$ and again geometrically the longest route with this constraint is $\sqrt{7^2+11^2}+\sqrt{9^2+1^2}$.

How did you decide upon choosing the point $(p+q,12)$, especially $12$ in particular.

I wanted the sum of the two lengths to be the expression in the question, so the first line needed to go from $(0,0)$ to $(p,u)$ and the second to go from $(p,u)$ to $(p+q, u+v)$, but $u+v=12$, from the condition $x+y=10$.

@mcd Your idea is very nice! But I think your answer is not complete. $a$ is a parameter (fixed but unknown). You claim that the minimum is clearly when the point $(p, u)$ lies on the line from $(0, 0)$ to $(p+q, 12)$. This is not always the case, since for some $a$, $(p, u)$ never lies on the line from  $(0, 0)$ to $(p+q, 12)$. For example, when $a = 3/2$, $p : q$ is never equal to $u:v$ since $x \in [0, 10]$ (unless $x < 0$, it can be $p:q = u: v$). In other words, when $a = 3/2$, the minimum occurs not when $p : q = u: v$. Do you need to address these cases?

Alternate Solution Outline :
When we eliminate $y$ & $b$ , we get :
$f(x,10-x)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{(10-x)^2+2(10-x)+132-a}$
We want to minimize this , hence we try with $f'(x)=0$ , with suitable $f''(x)$
Solving that , we will get $x$ in terms of $a$
With that , we will get the minima for $f$ in terms of $a$ , like $M(a)$
We write the Equation $Minima = M(a) = 20$ which will involve $a$
Solving that , we will get $a$ & hence $b$
Plug that $a$ back into $f(x,10-x)$
Now we want the maxima , hence we again go with $f'(x)=0$ , with suitable $f''(x)$ & with suitable Boundary Conditions.
That will give the maxima we want.
What is wrong with OP Solution :
(1) It is generating the Bounds via AM-GM & Cauchy-Schwarz , without considering whether that value is achieved/achievable.
(2) More-over , it is not considering the inter-relation between $x \leftrightarrow y$ & $a \leftrightarrow b$ , which will not let AM-GM & Cauchy-Schwarz work , because there it is assumed that there are no inter-relations between variables. That is not the Case here.
(3) OP rightly observes that not all information is used. Particularly , the minima is not used to get $a$ & $b$.
(4) The minima & maxima vary with $a$ & $b$ , where $a=b$ might not occur. Particularly , global minima is $\sqrt{101} \approx 14.21267040$ at $a=167,b=-35$ & $x=y=5$ [[ where $a+b=132$ & $x+y=10$ ]]
When we vary $a$ , we will increase the minima achievable & at some $a$ value , the minima will be $20$. We have to identify that $a$ value. We can not assume that $a=b$ here. When we know that $a$ value , we can try to get the Maxima there.

Great analysis. All my confusion got cleared immediately.

Unfortunately, your solution is incorrect for the reasons you suspect.
We can use calculus to obtain the correct solution.  Presently, I do not have a non-calculus approach.
We are given the constraints
$$x, y > 0 \tag{1}$$
$$x+y = 10 \tag{2}$$
$$a+b = 132 \tag{3}$$
$$\min_{x,y} f(x,y) = 20. \tag{4}$$
This suggests letting $$u = x+1, \quad v = y+1, \quad m = a-1, \quad n = b-1, \tag{5}$$ so that
$$\begin{align}
g(u) = f(x,y)
&= \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + a-1} + \sqrt{(y+1)^2 + b-1} \\
&= \sqrt{u^2 + m} + \sqrt{v^2 + n} \\
&= \sqrt{u^2 + m} + \sqrt{(12-u)^2 + 130-m}. \tag{6} \end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dg}{du} 
&= \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+m}} + \frac{u-12}{\sqrt{(12-u)^2+130-m}} \\
&= \frac{u g(u) - 12 \sqrt{u^2+m}}{\sqrt{u^2 + m} \sqrt{(12-u)^2+130-m}}.\tag{7}\end{align}$$
Consequently, $dg/du = 0$ when $u = u_0$ satisfying
$$u_0 g(u_0) = 12 \sqrt{u_0^2+m}, \tag{8}$$
and at this critical point, we require $g(u_0) = 20$.  Thus
$$m = \left(\frac{4}{3}u_0\right)^2, \tag{9}$$
which in turn implies
$$\begin{align}
20 = g(u_0) &= \sqrt{\frac{25}{9}u_0^2} + \sqrt{(12-u_0)^2 + 130-\frac{16}{9}u_0^2} \\
&= \frac{5}{3}u_0 + \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2466-216u_0-7u_0^2}. \tag{10}\end{align}$$
Solving $(10)$, we obtain
$$(u_0,m) \in \left\{\left(\frac{21}{4}, 49\right), \left(\frac{27}{4}, 81\right)\right\}, \tag{11}$$
which by symmetry, fully characterizes $f$ (i.e., interchanging $x$ with $y$ and $a$ with $b$ yields the same function).
The next step is to show that for a fixed $(a,b)$, $f(x,10-x)$ is convex over $x \in [0,10]$; thus there are no other critical points, and the maximum is attained at an endpoint of the interval.  This is asserted without proof.
Then we evaluate for $(a,b) = (50, 82)$
$$\begin{align}
f(0,10) &= \sqrt{2}(5+\sqrt{101}) \approx 21.2837 \\
f(10,0) &= \sqrt{82}+\sqrt{170} \approx 22.0938.
\end{align} \tag{12}$$
The latter value is the desired maximum.
Again, I make no claim that this is a satisfactory solution; however, it is the correct answer.  The reader is encouraged to fill in the gaps, as well as use this information to formulate a non-calculus based proof.

At your step (7) it simplifies the work if you write $$\frac{dg}{du}
= \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+m}} - \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2+n}}$$ so, at extrema, $$\frac{u^2}{v^2}=\frac{m}{n}.$$ Then $u$ and $v$ divide 12 in the ratio $\sqrt{m} : \sqrt{n}$.

Remark. The minimum $20$ is used to determine $a$ and $b$. With this pair $(a, b)$, we compute the maximum.
Problem. Let $a, b \ge 0$ be two given real numbers with $a + b = 132$ such that
the minimum of $f(x, y) := \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + a} + \sqrt{y^2 + 2y + b}$ subject to $x, y \ge 0$ and $x + y = 10$ is $20$. Find the maximum of $f(x,y)$.
Note that swapping $a$ and $b$ does not change the minimum and maximum of $f(x, y)$. WLOG, we may assume that $a \le b$.
Then $a \le 66$.
We claim that $a > 1$. Indeed, if $a \le 1$,
we have
$$f(0, 10) = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{252 - a} 
\le 1 + \sqrt{252} < 20.$$
Contradiction.
By Minkowski's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 f &= \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + \sqrt{a - 1}^2} + \sqrt{(y+1)^2+\sqrt{b-1}^2}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{(x + 1 + y + 1)^2 + (\sqrt{a - 1} + \sqrt{b - 1})^2}\\
 &= \sqrt{274 + 2\sqrt{(a-1)(b-1)}}\\
 &= \sqrt{274 + 2\sqrt{(a-1)(131-a)}}.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have $\sqrt{274 + 2\sqrt{(a-1)(131-a)}} \le 20$ which results in $a \le 50$. (Note: If $\sqrt{274 + 2\sqrt{(a-1)(131-a)}} > 20$,
then $f > 20$. Contradiction.)
We first check $a = 50$. When $a = 50$,
the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is exactly $20$ when $x = 17/4$ and $y = 23/4$ (take derivative). Is $a = 50$ unique? Yes, we have
$$f(17/4, 23/4) = \sqrt{a + \frac{425}{16}} + \sqrt{\frac{2825}{16} - a} \ge 20$$
which results in $a \ge 50$. Thus, $a = 50$.
We have
$$f(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 50} + \sqrt{y^2 + 2y + 82}.$$
We have
$$f(x, y) = g(x) := \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 50} + \sqrt{(10-x)^2 + 2(10-x) + 82}.$$
Since $g(x)$ is convex on $[0, 10]$ (easy).
We have, for all $x\in [0, 10]$,
$$g(x) \le \max(g(0), g(10)) = \sqrt{170}+\sqrt{82}.$$
Also, $g(10) = \sqrt{170}+\sqrt{82}$.
Thus, the maximum is $\sqrt{170}+\sqrt{82}$ when $x = 10, y = 0$.

Section 1.  Restatement of the Problem to Make it Easier to Reference in the Answer

Given that $x>0,y>0,x+y=10$ and $a+b=132$.
Let $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b} \tag{1}$$
If minimum value of $f(x,y)$ is $20$ then find the maximum value of $f(x,y)$.

Note: the condition that "minimum value of $f(x,y)$ is $20$" has no bearing on the maximum value.  I am not sure why that is part of the question.
Section 2.  Solution Steps
Given $x+y=10$, then $y=10-x$. And $b=132-a$. So:
$$\begin{align}f\left(x,y\right) &= \sqrt {x^2+2\,x+a}
+\sqrt{\left(10-x\right)^2+2\,\left(10-x\right)+132-a}
\\&=\sqrt {x^2+2\,x+a}+\sqrt{x^2-22\,x+142-a}
\end{align}$$
Consider the limit $x \to 0$, so in this case $y \to 10$ and
$f\left(x,y\right) \to \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{100+20+132-a}
\to \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{242-a}$.  And similarly with $y \to 0$, so in this case $x \to 10$ then $f\left(x,y\right) \to \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{100+20+132-b}
\to \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{242-b}$
Given the symmetry in Equation 1, it can also be rewritten with an additional symmetry parameter as:
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b}
\\&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+\frac1{2}\left(a+b\right)+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+\frac1{2}\left(a+b\right)-\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
\\&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66-\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
\end{align}$$
$$ \tag{Eqs. 2}$$
The maximum value of $\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)$ occurs when $\sqrt{y^2+2y+66-\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}=0$ and thus $y=10$; so the maximum value of $\left.\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)\right|_{maximum}=186$; and by the symmetry of $f\left(x,y\right)$ then $\left.\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)\right|_{minimum}=-186$. Either the maximum value of $\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)$ can be chosen for a maximum value of $f\left(x,y\right)$ given the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ there.
At the limit $a-b\to 0$ then (since $a-b=0$ results in twice the value for $f\left(x,y\right)$) so:
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(x,y\right)&=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66-\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
\\ &=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66}
\end{align}
$$
Now there are two extremes to consider, either $x=10, y=0$ (which results in the same $f\left(x,y\right)$ by symmetry as $x=0, y=10$.  Or alternatively, it needs also to be tested the valuation of $f\left(x=5,y=5\right)$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(x=10,y=0,a=b\right)&=
\left.\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}\right|_{x=10,y=0,a=b}\\
\\ &=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66}=\sqrt{10^2+2\times 10+66}=\sqrt{186}=13.638...
\end{align}$$
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(x=10,y=0,\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)=-186\right)&=
\left.\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}
\right|_{x=10,y=0,,\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)=-186}\\
\\ &=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66-186}+\sqrt{186}\\
&=\sqrt{186}=13.638...
\end{align}$$
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(x=5,y=5,a=b\right)&=
2\times \left.\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac1{2}\left(a-b\right)}\right|_{x=5,y=5,a=b}\\
\\ &=2\times \sqrt{x^2+2x+66}
\\&=2\times\sqrt{5^2+2\times 5+66}
=2\times\sqrt{101}=20.09975...
\end{align}$$
So the maximum is:
$$\boxed{
f(x=5,y=5,a=b)=2\times\sqrt{101}=20.09975...}$$
Section 3. 3-Dimentinonal Plot of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66}$ in the case $a=b$
Applying the on-line 3-dimentioal plotter from Desmos for $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66}$ in the case $a=b$ results in:




Section 4.  Additional Insight

Given that $x>0,y>0,x+y=10$ and $a+b=132$.
Let $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+a}+\sqrt{y^2+2y+b} \tag{1}$$
Find the maximum value of $f(x,y)$.

$$f\left(x,y\right)=\sqrt{x^2+2x+\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a-b}{2}}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}}=\tag{Eqs. 4.2}$$
$$=\sqrt{x^2+2x+66+\frac{a-b}{2}}
+\sqrt{y^2+2y+66+\frac{b-a}{2}}=\tag{Eqs. 4.3}$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2
+2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2}\right)+66+\frac{a-b}{2}}
+\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{y-x}{2}\right)^2
+2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{y-x}{2}\right)+66+\frac{b-a}{2}}=
\tag{Eqs. 4.4}$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(5+\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2
+2\left(5+\frac{x-y}{2}\right)+66+\frac{a-b}{2}}
+\sqrt{\left(5+\frac{y-x}{2}\right)^2
+2\left(5+\frac{y-x}{2}\right)+66+\frac{b-a}{2}}=
\tag{Eqs. 4.5}$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(25+5\,\left(x-y\right)
+\frac1{4}\left(x-y\right)^2\right)
+\left(10+\left(x-y\right)\right)+66+\frac{a-b}{2}}+
+\sqrt{\left(25+5\,\left(y-x\right)
+\frac1{4}\left(y-x\right)^2\right)
+\left(10+\left(y-x\right)\right)+66+\frac{b-a}{2}}
\tag{Eqs. 4.6}$$
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\sqrt{\left(101+6\,\left(x-y\right)
+\frac1{4}\left(x-y\right)^2\right)
+\frac{a-b}{2}}+\\
+\sqrt{\left(101+6\,\left(y-x\right)
+\frac1{4}\left(y-x\right)^2\right)
+\frac{b-a}{2}}
\tag{Eqs. 4.7}$$
Now there are additional boundary conditions that $x>0$ and $y>0$.  This translates to when $y\to 0_+ \underset{implies}\implies x\to 10_-$. And when $x\to 0_+ \underset{implies}\implies y\to 10_-$  By the symmetry of $f\left(x,y\right)$ either can be chosen if an extreme point maximizes $f\left(x,y\right)$.
It is possible to rewrite Equation 4.6 as:
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\frac1{2}\sqrt{\left(404+24\,\left(x-y\right)
+\left(x-y\right)^2\right)
+2\,\left(a-b\right)}+\\
+\frac1{2}\sqrt{\left(404+24\,\left(y-x\right)
+\left(y-x\right)^2\right)
+2\,\left(b-a\right)}
\tag{Eqs. 4.8}$$
$$f\left(x,y\right)=
\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(404-144+
  \left(
   \left(x-y
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(a-b \right)}+\\
+\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(404-144+
  \left(
   \left(y-x
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(b-a \right)}
\\
=\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(x-y
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(a-b \right)}+\\
+\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(y-x
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(b-a \right)}
\tag{Eqs. 4.9}$$
Additional solution steps are in progress.  However, this partial solution should be helpful to find any possible maximum values.  For instance, the limits $x>0$ and $x+y=10$ imply that $0<x<10$.  That then determines y as $y=10-x$.  So $\frac1{2}\left(x-y\right)=
\frac1{2}\left(x-\left(10-x\right)\right)=\left(x-5\right)$.  This can be substituted into Equation 4.9 to arrive at Equation 4.10 as follows:
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(x-y
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(a-b \right)}+\\
+\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(y-x
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(b-a \right)}$$
$$
=\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(2\,x-10
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(a-b \right)}+\\
+\frac1{2}\sqrt{
\left(260+
  \left(
   \left(10-2\,x
   \right)+12
  \right)^2 
\right)+2\,\left(b-a \right)}
\tag{Eqs. 4.10}$$
For the purposes of plotting this result in three dimensions, let $x\to x$, $y\to a-b$ and $f\left(x,y\right)\to z$.
Then consider the resulting quoted graph from the Desmos online calculator and plotter:



From this 3-d plot, the maximum occurs around
$f\left(\left(x \to 0\right),\left(y\to 10 \right)\right)\approx 22.075$.
The additional quoted plots (3-dimensional and 2-dimensional) reveal an updated maximum value for $f\left(x,y\right)$ as:
$$
\boxed{
f\left(x,y\right)_{\text{Maximum}}\approx 22.45
}$$
This is greater than $\sqrt{182}+\sqrt{70} \approx 21.857337829$, the previously mentioned maximum data point in the comments.







It should be $252$ instead of $242$

I can attempt to solve this with numerical computational methods but that can take more time than I have right now.  In the meanwhile, I appreciate your data point.

But the answer obtained by you is clearly not the maximum value. It comes when $x=10,y=0,a=82,b=50$ and the value thus obtained is $\sqrt{182}+\sqrt{70}\approx 22.28>20.09$

@StephenElliott $a$ is a parameter which is fixed but unknown (or to be determined). The minimum of $f(x, y)$ is a function of $a$. When $a$ varies, the minimum of $f(x,y)$ varies. When $a$ is equal to $a_0$, the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is exactly equal to $20$. So, the minimum $20$ is used to determine $a$. For this pair $(a, b)$, we seek the maximum of $f(x, y)$.
